# ST_Split returning a huge amount of rows

Tags: postgis

I am attempting to split a small road network at every intersection.  I started by creating points at every intersection in QGIS, that was no problem.  But now I am trying to split them using PostGIS and I am getting back 16000 rows, which is far more than reasonable.  I also checked and saw that there are many duplicated in the returned table.

I am not enormously experienced in PostGIS so it's likely that I am making a key mistake that I just can't see.

This is my query:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT((ST_Dump(ST_Split(streets_network.geom, nodes.geom))).geom) AS the_geom
FROM streets_network, nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're trying to split all streets using all nodes... as output you'll get at least count of nodes multiplied by count of streets...
2. You have to add to this value count 2xnodes intersecting with roads... if you have 1 road with 3 cutting nodes you'll get 6 pieces (as 2 splited in first point, 2 splited in second point and 2 splited in third point)
3. With a high probability it will not work at all cause of accuracy and roundings in database - it's almost impossible to hit to a line with a point which, by definition, is infinitely small.

As resolutions:

1. You have to cut the line only with points intersecting with it
2. Cut line with union of all points intersecting this street - one geometry with one (multi)geometry, so cutting with 3 points you'll get 4 lines.
3. Use ST_Buffer with some minimal value to expand points into very small circles
4. Or else.... use [pgr_nodeNetwork()](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/topology/doc/pgr_nodeNetwork.html#pgr-node-network) function from [pg_routing extension](http://pgrouting.org/documentation.html)